# scrapy formrequest not return values

Tags: scrapy

I followed the Scrapy documents to send post request. It didn't show error, but returned nothing.

```
return scrapy.FormRequest('https://www.crowdfunder.com/company/setInvestSection', formdata={'section':'company-custom',
                                                                                               'company_id':'22392'}, callback=self.parse_custom)

def parse_custom(self, response):
    print response.url
    print response.xpath('//section[@id="custom"]').extract_first()
```

Here is the log info:

```
    2016-10-26 13:50:52 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.crowdfunder.com/?q=filter&page=1> (referer: https://www.crowdfunder.com/)
    2016-10-26 13:50:55 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.crowdfunder.com/digitzs> (referer: https://www.crowdfunder.com/?q=filter&page=1)
    41840
    https://www.crowdfunder.com/digitzs
    2016-10-26 13:50:56 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.crowdfunder.com/company/setInvestSection> (referer: https://www.crowdfunder.com/digitzs)
    https://www.crowdfunder.com/company/setInvestSection
    <section id="custom" data-company-id="22392">
        </section>
    2016-10-26 13:50:56 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
    2016-10-26 13:50:56 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

[Here is the url and form data that I sent the Post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juova.png)

The wanted response from browser:

```
<section id="custom" data-company-id="22392">
          <h2 class="section-title">See Kevin Harrington Talk About Digitzs</h2>
    <div class="custom-content"><p><a href="https://youtu.be/gbLS0FsqYw8" target="_blank"><img src="https://com-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/site/company/custom/22392/site/custom_content/6cf1786e396758009a82aa1006b6148e.jpg" alt="Kevin Harrington Invests in Digitzs" /></a></p></div>
  </section>
```

The workable codes after using splash:

```
scrapy_splash.SplashFormRequest('https://www.crowdfunder.com/company/setInvestSection',
                                              self.parse_custom,
                                              meta={'company_id': company_id},
                                              formdata={'section':'company-custom','company_id':'22392'},
                                              endpoint='http://192.168.99.100:8050/render.html')
```

Comment: Could it be that the data your are looking for is generated by javascript? You can insert `inspect_response(response, self)` under your `parse` method and it will open up a shell for debugging during the crawl, then disable javascript and do `view(response)` in the debug shell to see what scrapy sees.

Comment: Your method is very helpful for debugging. The response showed nothing. I don't think it is generated by javascript. I checked the network in the console. The data was requested in the Ajax request when loading the page. I didn't know why I couldn't get the data using the same request as the browser.

Comment: That is correct, if the data is generated through ajax (which is powered by javascript) scrapy won't see it. Anything other than the html page you see in the networks tab will not be visible by scrapy. You either need to do those ajax requests manually (usually there are hints of what's going on in the html source) or use javascript rendering service like [splash](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/].

Comment: Thanks, here I found the ajax request 'https://www.crowdfunder.com/company/setInvestSection', and I sent the same request independently. Is it still impossible for scrapy to get the data?

Comment: Yes, however you need to look at the request in the network tab of your browser inspect tool and reverse engineer how the request is made.

Comment: The code of my post is the reverse engineer, but I didn't get the data. Now I'm using the splash as you suggested, it works now. Curiously, I don't what happened.  But thank you for the help!